# How to install shp2pgsql and raster2pgsql from source?

Tags: postgis, command-line, compile

I just installed PostGIS 2.4.0alpha from source by following [osgeo instructions](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS24Debian9src) on Ubuntu 16.04.

After installation, PostGIS seems to work. However, command line tools that are supposed to come with PostGIS are not installed.

For example, `shp2pgsql` is missing after `sudo make install`.

```
$ shp2pgsql
The program 'shp2pgsql' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install postgis
```

(similarly `raster2pgsql` is also missing).

Looking into the `postgis-2.4.0alpha/loader` folder, the executables `shp2pgsql` and `pgsql2shp` are present.

What steps do I need to do beyond `sudo make install` to install the command line tools such as `shp2pgsql` and `raster2pgsql`?

Comment: It is probably just a matter of adding a symlink or adding the psql/bin directory to your PATH in bashrc or similar. I install from packages these days and on my Ubuntu 16.04 box, it is in /usr/bin/shp2pgsql. However, in the old days, when I enjoyed breaking my system on a more regular basis :-), I recall that such things used to appear in <path_to>/psql/bin/. Also, have you run ldconfig? I often found that would solve a lot of post build linking issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this is a PATH issue as pointed out in @JohnPowellakaBarça comment. And I solved the problem by adding `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin` to system path.

Somehow `make install` in PostGIS 2.4.0alpha installed the binaries to the above folder but didn't install the symlinks to `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Glad it worked. These things can be a bit painful (though not as painful as using Windows, boviously :-))

Comment: Command to add to path:    export PATH="/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin:$PATH"
Replace 9.6 with you current postgres version